# Clarifai GUI. How to view the predictions for a specific file id

Tags: clarifai

I cannot find a way to find a specific file in a custom model via the online GUI. I have uploaded the file via the api along with several hundred images used for training. How can I filter the files displayed using the image id only. From there can I view the results of the prediction. I tried drag and drop and got a selected image displayed with a selected tick mark.
Anybody any idea where I go from here?
Or is there another way?

Comment: are you able to see your custom model within the left hand concepts/models panel? Within the UI, you should be able to view predictions for any images already within your app by clicking on them.

Comment: Yes I can see the custom model. The problem is finding the images to select. I have hundreds possibly thousands of images and I have found no way of filtering them. Using wild cards in an image id filter would be very useful

Comment: ah, i see. The UI doesn't currently support searching or filtering by metadata (id, url, create/update times, etc)... However there is a way to achieve this through the API. Have a look here:
https://developer-preview.clarifai.com/guide/searches#search-by-custom-metadata
that only covers custom metadata, but you can do the same with input attributes. Unfortunately there isn't wildcard support - so it's somewhat limited